# Julia: Iterating in reverse

Tags: julia

Let's say I have the following list:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Instead of stepping through the list from 1 to 5

```
for i in 1:length(a)
```

I would like to step through it from 5 to 1. Is there a convenient way to do this in Julia?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many options.

Do you want to iterate `a` in reverse or indices into `a`?

First assume you wan to iterate `a`, then `Iterators.reverse(a)` is an efficient way to do it.

If you want to iterate indices of `a` then an efficient option is `reverse(eachindex(a))`. You could also write `Iterators.reverse(eachindex(a))` but this time it is enough to use standard `reverse` function (I have not recommended it for reversing `a` as it would allocate a new vector).

Note that in your case it would be also correct to write `length(a):-1:1`, but this is not a recommended pattern in general, as you cannot be sure what pattern of indexing your `a` object supports (in your case it is a vector using 1-based indexing, but it could be an object that uses a different indexing style).

Comment: A follow up question, if I still choose to set up my loop as `for i in reverse(eachindex(a))` how could I still receive the index of the element on the "opposite end" of the vector? For example, `for i in reverse(eachindex(a))`  means that on the first iteration `a[i]` will return `5`, but what line of code could I write to still return `1` in that iteration?

Comment: `for (idx_from_start, idx_from_end) in zip(eachindex(a), reverse(eachindex(a)))`